# x and y axis tick spacing on subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, emoji, data-science

I can't seem to get the spacing of the keys of my subplots in matplotlib correct. I'd like for the keys on the x axis to line up to where the bars are coming up. In some plots, the markers on the y axis are also smushed in a weird way that I can't seem to find solutions for. Here is the code and graphs generated for reference.

```
EX. {'daniel': [#shares, #views, #comments, #likes, #total_engagement]}

def plotUserEngagement():

    keys = top_users.keys()
    f, metrics = plt.subplots(3, 2)

    for graph_data in [(0, 0, 'shares', 0), (0, 1, 'views', 1), (1, 0, 'comments', 2), (1, 1, 'likes', 3), (2, 0, 'Total Engagement', 3)]:
        x = graph_data[0]
        y = graph_data[1]
        engagement_metric = graph_data[2]
        index = graph_data[3]

        graph = metrics[x, y]
        graph.set_title('User ' + engagement_metric)
        user_metric_data = [engagement_by_user[user][index] for user in top_users]
        graph.bar(range(len(top_users)), user_metric_data)
        if [x,y] == [2,0]:
            graph.set_xticklabels(keys, rotation = 'vertical')

    metrics[2,1].set_xticklabels(keys, rotation = 'vertical')
    f.tight_layout()
```

[HERE ARE THE GRAPHS ATTACHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFYCL.png)

In the above example, I was expecting to see 10 user names on the bottom x axis, one for each of the 10 bar lines. I verified that the 'keys' variable actually does contain 10 items.

I'm having similar issues displaying emoji along the x axis in the following plots where I was expecting 10 emoji, one for each bar:
    keys = [emoji.decode('utf-8') for emoji in top_emojis]
    f, metrics = plt.subplots(2, 2)

```
def plotEmojiData():
    for graph_data in [(0, 0, 'Appearances', 0), (0, 1, 'Comments', 1), (1, 0, 'Likes', 2)]:
        x = graph_data[0]
        y = graph_data[1]
        emoji_characterictic = graph_data[2]
        index = graph_data[3]

        graph = metrics[x, y]
        graph.set_title('Emoji ' + emoji_characterictic)
        characteristic_data = [top_emojis[emoji][index] for emoji in top_emojis]
        graph.bar(range(len(top_emojis)), characteristic_data)
        graph.set_xticklabels(keys, fontname='symbola', fontsize=20)

plotEmojiData()

engagement_graph = metrics[1, 1]
engagement_graph.set_title('Emoji Total Engagement')
totalEngagement = [appearances[i]+comments[i]+likes[i] for i in range(len(top_emojis))]
engagement_graph.bar(range(len(top_emojis)), totalEngagement)
engagement_graph.set_xticklabels(keys, fontname='symbola', fontsize=20)

f.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[HERE ARE THE GRAPHS ATTACHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ2RC.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly set the correct number of ticks if you want all you labels to be displayed:

```
graph.bar(range(len(top_users)), user_metric_data)        
graph.set_xticks(range(len(top_users))  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
graph.set_xticklabels(keys, rotation = 'vertical')
```